# Is there a way to override a override a Territory Assignment Rule with a manual rule.

Tags: territory-management, territory

I want to use the Territory Assignment Rules for 90% of our prospects.  On the other 10%,  I may need to override the territory manually.  It is important to note - I only have one territory per prospect.

When I use the standard Assign Territory button it issues a 2nd territory verses allowing me to override the Territory Assignment Rule.  Is it possible to delete the Territory Assignment Rule  for just this one prospect and only display the Manual rule?

[image: Creates two territories and only one deletion option]

Answer (score 0):

There is a default field on Accounts "Exclude from Territory Assignment Rules", tick that checkbox and see if it work for you. Not sure if this checkbox will exclude also the Manual rule.

OR

Create a new custom field on accounts, populate it with "Manual", then in each assignment rule add a criteria to exclude accounts when the custom field is populated with "Manual".